# Can I use conditional statements with EJS templates (in JMVC)?

Tags: conditional-statements, ejs

and if yes, what is the syntax?
My goal is to prepend an 's' to the word 'comment' when there is more than one. in an jQuery.ejs template in a JMVC app. The following breaks. I can't find any docs for conditionals...

```
<%=commentsNumber%> comment<% if (commentsNumber > 1) { %> s <% } %>
```

Comment: Your syntax looks right, and works for me. Are you sure that var commentsNumber exists and is an integer?

Comment: Yes, strange that conditionals are not mentioned in the docs!

Answer (score 189, accepted):

For others that stumble on this, you can also use ejs params/props in conditional statements:

recipes.js File:

```
app.get("/recipes", function(req, res) {
    res.render("recipes.ejs", {
        recipes: recipes
    });
});
```

recipes.ejs File:

```
<%if (recipes.length > 0) { %>
// Do something with more than 1 recipe
<% } %>
```

Comment: Can you, in the case of an `include` statement, write the conditional inline? That is writing `<% if (true) { include foo/bar } %>` appears to error. Is there a method similar or is it necessary to break out the `include` by `<% %>`.

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for this answer before trying it out.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to display conditional elements from changes on the server. Your answer showed me that I needed to do have evaluate everything on the client.

Answer (score 246):

Conditionals work if they're structured correctly, I ran into this issue and figured it out.

For conditionals, the tag before `else` has to be paired with the end tag of the previous `if` otherwise the statements will evaluate separately and produce an error.

ERROR!

```
<% if(true){ %>
   <h1>foo</h1>
<% } %>
<% else{ %>
   <h1>bar</h1>
 <% } %>
```

Correct

```
<% if(true){ %>
   <h1>foo</h1>
 <% } else{ %>  
   <h1>bar</h1>
<% } %>
```

hope this helped.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful as I was running into an issue where I was putting my `else` on a different line like the first code block you mentioned.  Thanks so much for including these examples!!

Comment: I too was facing same issue, correct structure solved the problen

Answer (score 37):

Yes , You can use conditional statement with EJS like if else , ternary operator or even switch case also

For Example

**Ternary operator** : 
`<%- role == 'Admin' ? 'Super Admin' : role == 'subAdmin' ? 'Sub Admin' : role %>`

**Switch Case**

```
<% switch (role) {
case 'Admin' : %>
        Super Admin
        <% break;

case 'eventAdmin' : %>
        Event Admin
        <% break;

case 'subAdmin' : %>
        Sub Admin
        <% break;

} %>
```

Comment: Happy to see switch statement works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

EJS seems to behave differently depending on whether you use { } notation or not:

I have checked and the following condition is evaluated as you would expect:

```
<%if (3==3) {%>  TEXT PRINTED  <%}%>
<%if (3==4) {%>  TEXT NOT PRINTED  <%}%>
```

while this one doesn't:

```
<%if (3==3) %>  TEXT PRINTED  <% %>
<%if (3==4) %>  TEXT PRINTED  <% %>
```

Comment: Would you expect a single space character to do something?

Answer (score 22):

You can also use `else if` syntax:

```
<% if (x === 1) { %>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
<% } else if (x === 2) { %>
    <p>Hi earth!</p>
<% } else { %>
    <p>Hey terra!</p>
<% } %>
```

Comment: what you need to highlight here is that the closing bracket has to **most definitively** be used in the same line as else/else if

Answer (score 8):

I know this is a little late answer,

you can use if and else statements in ejs as follows

```
<% if (something) { %>
   // Then do some operation
<% } else { %>
   // Then do some operation
<% } %>
```

But there is another thing I want to emphasize is that if you use the code this way,

```
<% if (something) { %>
   // Then do some operation
<% } %>
<% else { %>
   // Then do some operation
<% } %>
```

It will produce an error.

Hope this will help to someone

Answer (score 4):

***one simple and general rule***
for embedding javascript for example (for loops)  into our ejs template we can follow the following rule:

1. first write your javascript code in the ejs template as you normally write in the javascript.
2. put the <%  in the start and %> in the end of every pure javascript line.

***for example:***

```
if (num%2===0) {
    <p> this is an even number</p>
} else { 
<p> this is an odd number</p>
}
```

**so now we have to put the ejs syntax in every line :**

```
 <% if (num%2===0) {%>
    <p> this is an even number</p>
<%} else { %>
<p> this is an odd number</p>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just making code shorter you can use ES6 features. The same things can be written as

```
app.get("/recipes", (req, res) => {
    res.render("recipes.ejs", {
        recipes
    });
});
```

And the Templeate can be render as the same!

```
<%if (recipes.length > 0) { %>
// Do something with more than 1 recipe
<% } %>
```