# After user login change links from login to logout in Node.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am using passport.js for user authentication, user is successfully logging in.
and now I try to change the navigation links i.e Login to logout after user successfully logged in.

for that I am using the following middleware in app.js file

```
  var express=require('express');
var path=require('path');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
var cookieParser=require('cookie-parser');
var passport=require('passport');
var LocalStrategy=require('passport-local').Strategy;
var expressSession=require('express-session');
var app=express();
require('./db');
    var userModel=require('./models/usermodel');
    var adminModel=require('./models/adminmodel');

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
  next(); });


//Configuring Routes
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var register = require('./routes/register');
var login = require('./routes/login');
var admin = require('./routes/admin');
var addblog = require('./routes/addblog');
var admindashboard = require('./routes/admindashboard');
var adminviewblog = require('./routes/admin-view-blog');
var viewblog = require('./routes/view-blog');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// app uses configuration
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'routes/uploads')));
app.use(expressSession({ secret: 'keyboard catoard cat' }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/register', register);
app.use('/login', login);
app.use('/admin', admin);
app.use('/addblog', addblog);
app.use('/admindashboard', admindashboard);
app.use('/admin-view-blog', adminviewblog);
app.use('/view-blog', viewblog);

//passport configuration

   /*=======passport configuration========*/
passport.use("userss", new LocalStrategy(userModel.authenticate()));
passport.use("adminn", new LocalStrategy(adminModel.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
    });
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    userModel.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
        });

    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    adminModel.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
        });

    });


//create server
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server is running  localhost:3000');
    });
```

and in ejs template

```
<% if login %>
        <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
        <% else %> 
         <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
        <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li> 
        <% endif %>
```

But its not working. 
the page showing the following errors.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in F:\saurabh_sharma\nodejs\blogsystem\views\index.ejs while compiling ejs
   at Function (native)
   at Object.Template.compile (F:\saurabh_sharma\nodejs\blogsystem\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:464:12)
```

I googled this problem but didn't find the solution.

If someone have idea about this please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you should have two definitions of `deserializeUser()`

Comment: ok...after removing extra deserializeUser(), still its not working

Comment: what is your code for passport strategies??

Comment: this is the passport strategy i am using
passport.use("userss", new LocalStrategy(userModel.authenticate()));
passport.use("adminn", new LocalStrategy(adminModel.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
    });
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    userModel.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
        });

    });
    passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    adminModel.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
        });

    });

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect!

```
<% if(true){ %>
<h1>foo</h1>
<% } %>
<% else{ %>
<h1>bar</h1>
<% } %>
```

Correct

```
<% if(true){ %>
<h1>foo</h1>
<% } else{ %>  
<h1>bar</h1>
<% } %>
```

Please structure your conditionals correctly.

Reference: [Can I use conditional statements with EJS templates (in JMVC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216918/can-i-use-conditional-statements-with-ejs-templates-in-jmvc)

Comment: Please try to print the value tof `login` in your template to verify if the value of `login` is passed to the template or not

Comment: when I am printing <%= login%> in my template its showing boolean "false" after replace req.locals with app.locals

Comment: yes initially the user is not logged in so `login` should be equal to `false`. So we have to write `<%if (login == false)%>`. Please try this

Comment: you are talking about this??? <%if (login == false){%>
  <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
  <% } else { %>
   <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
  <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li> 
  <% } %>

Comment: <%if (login == false){%> <li><a href="/login">Login</a></li> <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li> <% } else { %> <li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li> <% } %>

Comment: I think there is something missed in middleware of authenticating the user.

Comment: does _not working_ means that both the links are visible on your page? Try to print the value of `login` after you login your user. If it is always `false` then there is some problem in your middleware

Comment: both conditions are not printing..only the if condition is printing in both action in while user logged in or not

Comment: it seems the problem of your middleware then. If you need help debugging it then please update your question with its code

Answer (score 0):

```
<% if (login) { %>
<li><a href="/logout">Logout</a></li>
<% } else { %> 
<li><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
<li><a href="/register">Register</a></li> 
<% } %>
```

Comment: I did it,  error is removed but its not changing the links.

Comment: You should check what is in `login`

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
  next(); });  above middleware is not working properly.

Comment: Can you edit your proposed answer to expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

first make a global variable in app.js or server.js in your main file

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
});
```

and then apply like this in your navbar

```
            <%if (!user) { %>
                <li><a href="/user">login</a></li>
                <% }else{ %>
                    <li><a href="/user/logout">logout</a></li>
                    <%}%>
```