# Conditional operators in ejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io, conditional-statements, ejs

This might sound really easy.  There is a [very similar
answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14201112/6060916) but somehow my code is behaving abruptly and driving me crazy. I have spent last 4-5 hours on this.  Any help would be great.

I am building a Socket.IO chat app using Node + Express + Passport.  I want to compare the userId of the current user with that of other users connected.  I want to show him all users except himself to chat with in Socket.IO.

Read comments on code for clarity :

users.js

```
app.get('/users', function (req, res) {

var connectedUsers = require('../app').chatUsers; // =>  This is an array of all logged in user and I am getting this all correctly.

if (req.isAuthenticated()) {

    res.render('users', {
        currentUser: req.user,
        users: connectedUsers,
        title: 'OnLineUsers'

    });
}
});
```

users.ejs

```
<h3>CurrentUser : <%- currentUser.id %></h3> // => This Prints like **abcdefg**


<% for(var i = 0;i < users.length ; i++){ %>

<h3>UserID: <%- users[i].id %></h3> // => This also prints the same **abcdefg** if only one user is connected.

<% if( currentUser.id !== users[i].id){ %> // => But this Conditional Operator  does not works and show the current user himself.

<ul>
    <li>
        <h3> <%= users[i].name %></h3>
        <a href="/socket" id="chatRoomUrl">
            <button type="submit" class="btn-success">Chat</button>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>

<% } %>
<% } %>
```

Thanks in advance. If there is any silly mistake on my part, please excuse me for wasting your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Maybe there is space in two property. Try :

```
currentUser.id.trim() !== users[i].id.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your following line, notice the change:

```
<h3> <%= users[i].name %></h3>
```

to this:

```
<h3> <%- users[i].name %></h3>
```