# How can I use if statement in ejs?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I have a page that makes a foreach and show some photos like this

```
<% imgs.forEach(function(img) { %>
      <img src="uploads/<%=user.username%>/screenshots/<%= img %>">
 <% }); %>
```

And I want make a if statement because, in case that not photos to show gives a message like this:

> "no photos uploaded"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<% if(imgs.length > 0){ %>
    <% imgs.forEach(function(img) { %>
        <img src="uploads/<%=user.username%>/screenshots/<%= img %>">
    <% }); %>
<% } else{ %>  
    <p>no photos uploaded</p>
<% } %>
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216918/can-i-use-conditional-statements-with-ejs-templates-in-jmvc)

Comment: This works well but do ejs support nested if else loop?

Comment: @xetryDcoder I have not tried it, but it should work the same way single `if-else` works. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: @DanielMSánchez can you share an example? or probably ask a new question with your particular usecase

Answer (score 5):

> The shorthand version is correct, but it does have a syntax error

```
<%= role === 'admin' ? 'Super Admin' : 'Admin' %>
```

> Or

```
<% if(role === 'admin'){ %>
    <p>Super Admin</p>
<% } else{ %>
    <p>Admin</p>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes , Here is short hand version :

`<%= role == 'A' ? 'Super Admin' : 'Admin'  %>`

Comment: It should actually be `<%= role == 'A' ? 'Super Admin' : 'Admin' %>`, with only one `?`. Your code results in a Syntax Error

Comment: My bad it was a typo .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this...?

```js
<% if (kindOfDay === "Sarturday" || kindOfDay === "Sunday") { %>
  <h1 style="color: green;"><%= kindOfDay %> Todo List</h1>
<% } else { %>
  <h1 style="color: blue;"><%= kindOfDay %> Todo List</h1>
<% } %>
```