# Compound if statements in ejs template

Tags: javascript, ejs

Is it possible to use compound if statements in an ejs template:

`<% if(this.thing == 'winner' || that.thing == 'winner') { %>`

I know you can use if statements in ejs. I am specifically looking for an example of `compound` if statements which cannot be used in all js templating schemes.

Comment: https://ionicabizau.github.io/ejs-playground/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use if statement in ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202233/how-can-i-use-if-statement-in-ejs)

Comment: @CharlieH I saw that post. I'm asking about `compound` if statements and not if statements in general

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `ejs` supports compound statements:

```
<%
    var fruits = ["Apple", "Pear", "Orange", "Lemon"];
%>

These fruits are amazing:
<% for(var i = 0; i < fruits.length; ++i) {%>
    <% if (fruits[i] == 'Apple' || fruits[i] == 'Lemon') {%>
        - <%=fruits[i]%>s
   <% }%>
<% } %>
```

Output:

```
These fruits are amazing:

        - Apples

        - Lemons
```

Thank you @JakeHolzinger

Answer (score 1):

Of course yes -

```
<% x = 5 %>

<% if(x === 4 || x === 5) { console.log('foo')}%>
```