# .ejs file will display some information but not all of it from my API JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, ejs

So I'm trying to get my .ejs file to display some more information from my API code but it keeps giving me an error code.

```
TypeError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/sportsapp/views/results.ejs:7
   5|         <li><%= game["home"]["name"]%> Vs.<%=game["away"]["name"]%>
   6|         <ul>
>> 7|             <li><%= game["broadcast"]["network"]%></li>
   8|         </ul>
   9|         </li>
   10|     </ul>

Cannot read property 'network' of undefined
```

I'm trying to get my ejs to display the game's home team name, away team name and also what network that the game is on, but I can only figure out how to display the team names for both the home and away teams.

Below is the API I am using

```
{
id: "6641572c-b588-4b0e-8671-e279ced1985b",
status: "scheduled",
coverage: "full",
scheduled: "2017-02-18T17:00:00+00:00",
conference_game: true,
venue: {
id: "e1276102-db24-4188-9558-f249d69526f5",
name: "William D. Mullins Center",
capacity: 9493,
address: "200 Commonwealth Ave",
city: "Amherst",
state: "MA",
zip: "1003",
country: "USA"
},
broadcast: {
network: "NBCSN",
satellite: "220"
},
home: {
name: "Massachusetts Minutemen",
alias: "MASS",
id: "88104678-e53b-43b3-82f7-efb3a11cedb9"
},
away: {
name: "Davidson Wildcats",
alias: "DAV",
id: "2920c5fa-1e86-4958-a7c4-1e97b8e201d8"
}
},
```

Here is my ejs file

```
<% data["games"].forEach(function(game){ %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= game["home"]["name"]%> Vs.<%=game["away"]["name"]%>
        <ul>
            <li><%= game["broadcast"]["network"]%></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
<% }); %>
```

And this is my express node app with the API key removed.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var request = require ("request");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

// this is getting information from the API and returning results in the ejs.
app.get("/sportsapp", function(req, res){
request("https://api.sportradar.us/ncaamb-t3/games/2017/02/18/schedule.json?api_key=", function(error, response, body){
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(body);
          res.render("results", {data : data});
       }
  });   
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Sports App has Started");
});
```

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong with the looping part of the ejs file but I'm not sure exactly where I'm screwing up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: log your game["broadcast"] value, are you sure all games in this array has property of game.broadcast.network?

Comment: @Kotel_ when I console.logged it it gave me this TypeError: Cannot read property 'broadcast' of undefined 

So I'm assuming not every array has that value, how do I go about getting it to display the ones that do have that value and then just display a blank if it doesn't?

Comment: I think @Kotel_ is right here.... while the JSON entry you've shown *does* have a `broadcast` key, it's most likely that there is an entry that *doesn't* and is causing the error you're seeing. You should check for its existence first before trying to access it.

Comment: @mscdex Yes he was correct, so now I'm wondering how I access the ones that do exist without getting that error. Or how do I replace the ones that don't exist with "does't exist" or something similar? Should I do a loop?

Comment: @Branduo you can use if statement and print only if property exist: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216918/can-i-use-conditional-statements-with-ejs-templates-in-jmvc
`<li><% (game.home ? game.home.name : 'does\'t exist') %> Vs.<% (game.away ? game.away.name : 'does\'t exist')%>`

Comment: @Kotel_ thank you for the help!