# Using Conditionals with variables in EJS

Tags: javascript, ejs

I have the following which is working as intended:

```
<%= employee.title %>, Support Member
```

I am trying to add a conditional such as:

```
<% if(!employee.title.includes('Junior')){ %>
    employee.title
<% } %>
Support Member
```

However it seems that it no longer has access to "employee" as it prints out the literal "employee.title".

I have referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216918/can-i-use-conditional-statements-with-ejs-templates-in-jmvc) thread for syntax help but have had no luck. Does anyone spot my issue? I couldn't find documentation help online.

Comment: you have also wrap it as `<%= employee.title %>` inside to tell your view engine here is an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do:

```
<% if(!employee.title.includes('Junior')){ %>
  <%= employee.title %>
<% } %>
Support Member
```

Check [Docs](http://ejs.co/#docs).

Comment: Thanks! I actually was initially wrapping it but I think I accidentally wrapped `<%=` with `%>` which threw me off.