# Can anyone tell me why my if/else statement isn't working in EJS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, if-statement, ejs

I'm trying to have a different image show up based on an integer taken from a SQL table. The SQL is working elsewhere, so I was wondering can anyone tell me why my if/else isn't working?

```
<% if (data.PatientId === 1) {%>
<img id="imgThumb" src="../images/old_person1.jpg" alt="patient_001">
<%} else if (data.PatientID === 2) {%>
<img id="imgThumb2" src="../images/old_person2.jpg" alt="patient_002">
<%} else if (data.PatientID === 3) {%>
<img id="imgThumb3" src="../images/old_person3.jpg" alt="patient_003">
<%} else if (data.PatientID === 4) {%>
<img id="imgThumb4" src="../images/old_person4.jpg" alt="patient_004">
<% } %>
```

Edit: data is a variable storing a row of a MySQL table in a for each statement.

Second edit: Thank you tyme, I assumed it was an issue with my code.

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? What is the value of "data"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24877667/1606432 I think this answers your question, looks like a specific ejs format

Comment: you use `PatientId` in the first `if` - then `PatientID` in the rest?